# Plot function in window

Tags: python, graph, plot

Create a method `plot(window, expression, color = "black")` to plot the expression in the
window.
This is what i've done:

```
from math import *
from graphics import *
win = GraphWin()

def plot(window, expression, color = "black"):
    #Evaluates given expression and plots it in "window". Returns the list of all the                                       plotted points.

    points = []

    #Evalute expression over 1000 different values and for each (x,y) pair plot the point.

    for i in range(0, 1001):
        try:
            x = i/100.0
            y = eval(expression)
            plot(x,y)

        except Exception:
            print("For ", x, " the expression is invalid")

    return points
```

So i guess i have done something wrong. Can someone help me? :)

Comment: Why do you guess you've done something wrong? Do you get errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: What is wrong ? Error message ? Unexpected behaviour ?

Comment: seems you forget to use the `points` list which you define in the start of the function?

Comment: When i run it just comes an infitinte long list of numbers that are invalid. Even if they should be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code you have a function called plot that calls plot - this is because of the classic error of from somewhere import *.

I suspect that you are trying to call graphics.plot within plot so get rid of the from graphics import * and put graphics. before the items that you are using from there.

You are also not filling in, or using your points list.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of obvious problems:

1. You create a list of `points`, never put anything into it, then `return` it (still empty) at the end; and
2. For each individual point `x, y` you call `plot` again recursively (see Steve Barnes' answer), passing `x` as `window` and `y` as `expression`.

I suggest you separate this into two parts: one to create a list of points based on the function, and one to plot this list of points.

Answer (score 0):

1. don't use the name `plot` as your own function name, this will shadow the `matplotlib.pyplot.plot` method name if you have `import *`.
2. the matplotlib `plot` method is used to create lines, which needs ***a series of*** Xs and Ys each time you call it. E.g., `plot(1,2)` or `plot([1], [2])` will plot **nothing** in the figure, while `plot([1,2], [3,4])` draws a line between point (1,3) and (2,4). You need to call `scatter(1, 2)` if you insist on plotting one point each time.